# Trying to reset parse user passwords with Cloud Code but getting error 141

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Here is my code,

```
Parse.Cloud.define("resetPassword", function(request, response){
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);

query.first({
    success: function(theUser){
        var newPassword = request.params.password;
        console.log("New Password: " + newPassword);

        console.log("set: " + theUser.set("password", newPassword));
        console.log("setPassword: " + theUser.setPassword(newPassword));

        theUser.save(null,{
            success: function(theUser){
                // The user was saved correctly
                response.success(1);
            },
            error: function(SMLogin, error){
                response.error("No se pudo guardar la contraseña");
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error){
        response.error("No se encontró al usuario");
    }
});
});
```

when the function is called from the ios app it seems to run but give and error.

Here is the error I get:

> error: Failed running cloud function assignPasswordToUser for user
>   LODC5xe5LS with:   Input:
>   {"username":"Administrator","password":"apple"}   Error:
>   {"code":141,"message":"error and stuff[object Object]"}
>   functionName=assignPasswordToUser, code=141, message=error and
>   stuff[object Object], username=Administrator, password=apple,
>   user=LODC5xe5LS error: Error generating response. ParseError { code:
>   141, message: 'error and stuff[object Object]' } code=141,
>   message=error and stuff[object Object] [object Object]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `useMasterKey` option on each method.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('redefineSenhaUsuario', function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

  query.equalTo("cpf", request.params.cpfUsuario);

  query.first({
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(usuario){
        var novaSenha = request.params.novaSenha;

        usuario.setPassword(novaSenha);

        usuario.save(null,{
            useMasterKey: true,
            success: function(usuario){
                // The user was saved correctly
                response.success("1");
            },
            error: function(error){
                response.error("Erro ao salvar nova senha");
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error){
        response.error("Erro no first" + error);
    }
  });
});
```